# changing button text when clicked and changing it back when clicked again

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

how can i change the text of a button when clicked? and change it back when clicked again? i have this javascript i made.and its not giving me what i want.please help?

```
    $('#addbtn').click(function (){
    if(document.getElementById('addMat').style.display == "none"){
        document.getElementById('addMat').style.display= "inline";
        $(this).val('Cancel');
    }else
        document.getElementById('addMat').style.display= "none";
        $(this).val('Add Material');
});
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery (`$('#addbtn').click(function (){`) and pure JS (`document.getElementById('addMat').style.display == "none"`)?

Comment: I "think" your $(this) will reference the #addMat element, and not the #addbtn element. Is that what you want? A tiny bit of HTML will help since I am not sure which element is the button.

Comment: You can do this in pure CSS using the focus() Psuedo Class. Create two buttons, with one display none. On focus() show the other button with a higher z-index. Twitter uses this format in its tweet buttons

Comment: @Mooseman is that wrong? sorry.im just new here.

Comment: @Leeish, can i reference the button inside this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it all with jQuery syntax:

```
$('#addbtn').click(function (){
    var addMat = $('#addMat');
    if( addMat.css('display')  === 'none' ) {
      addMat.css('display','inline');
      $(this).val('Cancel');
    } else {
      addMat.css('display','none');
      $(this).val('Add Material');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#addbtn').click(function (){
    if(document.getElementById('addMat').style.display === "none"){
        document.getElementById('addMat').style.display = "inline";
        $(this).attr("value","Cancel");
    }else{
        document.getElementById('addMat').style.display = "none";
        $(this).attr("value","Add Material");
    }
});
```

or Better...

```
$('#addbtn').click(function (){
    if( $('#addMat').css('display')  === 'none' ){
      $('#addMat').css('display','inline');
      $(this).attr("value","Cancel");
    } else {
      $('#addMat').css('display','none');
      $(this).attr("value","Add Material");
    }
});
```

Comment: .attr will only work if the OP is using jquery versions older than 1.6

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).prop('value', 'Cancel');
```

or

```
$(this).html('Cancel');
```

The Best way to do it is create a button and put a span tag around the text

```
$("span", this).text("My NEW Text");
```